# How to change ProgressIndicator to an icon when reaching a certain condition with javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a separate class that initializes a bunch of progress indicator for my GUI

```
public class ProgressIndicators {
    private ProgressIndicator firstIndicator;
    private ProgressIndicator secondIndicator;
    private ProgressIndicator thirdIndicator;

    public void initalizeIndicators() {

        //Initialize indicators and set properties
    

    }

}
```

I have another class that performs some heavy backend calculations in another class

```
public class HeavyCalculations {

    private boolean isFinished;

    public HeavyCalculations() {
        isFinished = false;
        doHeavyCalculations()
    }

    public doHeavyCalculations() {
        // Do Heavy Calculations that may take up to ten minutes
        isFinished = true; // Set isFinished to true once heavy calculations are done
    }

}
```

Once the `isFinished` variable is set to true, I would like to remove one of the `ProgressIndicator` and change it to another icon. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Is the progress indicator being updated based on the “heavy calculations”? Should the progress indicator change to something else when it reaches 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you know that if it reaches that line is finished, so you are in control, without the need of sharing any flag.

```
public doHeavyCalculations() {
    isFinished = true;
    removeProgressIndicator(); 
}
```

Simply implement the logic you need in order to know which `ProgressIndicator` you want to remove, and how to remove it, inside `removeProgressIndicator()` method.

If the `HeavyCalculations` class owns an instance of `ProgressIndicators`, it could be implemented in that class. Or without the need of an instance, by calling a static method.

For example, using an instance and with an int id param:

```
public doHeavyCalculations() {
    isFinished = true;
    indicatorInstance.removeProgressIndicator(1); 
}
```

.

```
public class ProgressIndicators {
   private ProgressIndicator firstIndicator;
   private ProgressIndicator secondIndicator;
   private ProgressIndicator thirdIndicator;

   public void removeProgressIndicator(int id) {
      //remove logic
   }
 }
```

I would suggest storing the `Indicators` in a List, so you could retrieve/add/remove them easily.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I was thinking I had to implement observable but this works and is very simple